# Parsing JavaScript String to Object

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing, object

I'm currently working on something which requires me to turn a string into a Javascript object. I've tried so many different things, looked up answers on here but none of them really seem to match my problem.

So this is what I have to do: I need to get the content of a JS file, that looks something like this: (I get the content with a simple HTTP get)

```
initiateOptions({
    fullscreen: true,
    showController: true,
    introModal: true,
    client: {
        name: 'Easyfairs - Flanders Expo',
        city: 'Gent',
        googlePlaceId: 'xxx'
    },
    preloadImages: {
        client: 'easyfairs_flandersexpo'
    },
    languages: ['EN','FR','NL'],
    logo: 'images/logo_wit.png',
    css: ['https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans', '/css/event- 
room-card.css', '/css/easyfairs.css'],
    color: '#99cc33',
    explainerImage: ['media/explainerImage.png'],
    /*customTexts: {
        switchYes: [{ "language":"NL", "text":"Beurs" },{ "language":"EN", 
"text":"Exhibition" },{ "language":"FR", "text":"Exhibition" }],
        switchNo: [{ "language":"NL", "text":"Leeg" },{ "language":"EN", 
"text":"Empty" },{ "language":"FR", "text":"Vide" }]
    },*/
});
```

I have to use the data inside of this file, so I want to turn it into a JS object that I can properly work with. I get the content of the file as a string, so I can remove the surrounding function with string manipulation etc.

As you can see, it's a JS object, wrapped in a function, which also contains commented lines. I find it really hard to make it work, I know there's a way to make it work using eval() but I'd rather not use that.

Anyone can help me out? Thanks in regards.

PS: I have no control over the workflow, this is the way the project is structured, so I need to make it work this way.

Comment: This is a horrifying requirement. You have a file you have to use with no control over the file, so you have to somehow get the file as a string and then use string manipulation to get what you need? My suggestion, try to push back hard against this requirement. It's insane.

Comment: Normally, I would ask why you didn't want to use eval()  but in this case it is pretty clear, and in fact, many (most/all?) of the alternatives are going to be equally dangerous.

Comment: do you getting stringifying object from GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- use a javascript parser, like Esprima, feed your js to it and walk the AST to reconstruct the object
- use `eval`, along the lines of

```js
js = `initiateOptions({
    fullscreen: true,
    showController: true,
    introModal: true,
    // etc
})`


let initiateOptions = x => x;
let result = eval(js);
console.log(result)
```

Do not try to use string functions, regexes, etc to parse it - you'll just waste your time.

Comment: I can't emphasise enough how dangerous it is to be using eval() on data from a URL

Comment: @MikeBrockington: well, probably because "someone can delete all your files"?

Comment: So Esprima would be my only option?

Comment: @GustDeprez: depends... is this an one-off task, or something you'll be doing on a regular basis? Also, is this client-side or node?

Comment: Happens client side, but I know for a fact no people with bad intent will use the thing I'm building. I just wish there was an easy way for this to work

Comment: @GustDeprez: if this is client side, then that code is from your own domain, right?

Comment: @GustDeprez: if you control the code and can be sure there's nothing harmful in it (e.g. no functions called etc), then nothing stops you from using eval. Technically, it would be much better to get the same data as JSON though.

Comment: I simply have to upvote because this is so clever :) But also because it's the only answer here that *actually works*. The others simply do not and *cannot* work with OP's data.